# Copy data range and paste to new page, and repeat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a range from sheet 'Full' and paste the values only to a new sheet, 'Dump'. While the macro below does its action once, I am regenerating the original data range (Full), so I want to copy that new set and append to the same output page, indexed down to a blank row and keeping the first pasted data. Also then to do this 100 times.
The recoded macro is below, and I need to understand the script to add in to;

- repeat the copy/paste function 100 times, and also
- offset the paste range by a set number of rows.

Sorry, genuine newbie at editing google sheet macros. The Excel macro I use doesn't translate over.
Appreciate any answers you have.

````
function xmacro() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Full'), true);
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dump'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('Full!BK3:BT34').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);```
};
````

Comment: Working with macros will only get you this far. You need to learn to work with sheets and ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro is just an automatically generated app script.  You can extend its functionality by building off that with some more code.  First I'll explain some of the basic concepts, if you know this, then just skip down to the code.

**Sheets Concepts**

Here are some basic concepts that took me forever to figure out because most of the documentation assumes you are already proficient at Javascript.

A range is a 2 dimensional array that has one array for each row, and the contents of that array are the columns:

```
someRange = [
              [row1Col1, row1Col2, row1Col3, row1Col4], 
              [row2Col1, row2Col2, row2Col3, row2Col4], 
              [row3Col1, row3Col2, row3Col3, row3Col4]
            ]
```

To access a specific value you need to reference the row array, and then the index of the column you want.
Think about it like hotel room numbers.   The first part of the number is the floor,
and the second part is the specific room on that floor.

You access arrays by calling the array name, then square brackets with the index number of the element you want.

Arrays are indexed starting at 0, so to get row 1 you would use:

`someRange[0] would return the inner array [row1Col1, row1Col2, row1Col3]`.

But that doesn't give you a specific cell values - so you would use a second set of brackets to access the column in that row:
`someRange[0][1]  =  'row1Col2'`

Arrays also have built in information, so you can find the length of an array by using  Array.length  no parenthesis.

Since the rows are in the outer array, you can get the number of rows by seeing how many inner arrays there are.

`someRange.length  = 3`   There are 3 row arrays in the someRange array.

You can do the same with columns, since the number of columns is equal to the number of elements in an array. To get the number of elements in the first row you would use:

`someRange[0].length  - which would be 4` 
And since a range has the same number of columns for each row, you can pick any row
to get the number of columns (generally, there are always exceptions)

**The Code**

The first function will create a custom menu item to run the code.

```
// create a new menu item for your custom function
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu()
                        .addItem('100 Copies', 'lotsOfCopies')
                        .addToUi();
}

function lotsOfCopies() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName('yourCopySheetName');
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName('yourPasteSheetName');
  
  // the range you wish to copy, change to fit your needs
  var copyRange = copySheet.getRange('A1:B7');
  var copyValues = copyRange.getValues();
  

  var copyRows = copyValues.length;
  var copyCols = copyValues[0].length;

  // define the first row to be pasted into
  var pasteRow = 1;
  
  // define the left side column of the range to be pasted into
  var pasteCol = 1

  // build a loop that does the same thing 100 times, 
  // and each time offsets the paste range by the number of rows in the copy range

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // for every iteration after the first, 
    // add the number of rows in the copy range to the variable 'row'
    // example if there are 10 rows in the copy range then 
    // iteration 1 row = 1   Iterartion 2 row = 11,  Iteration 3 row = 21
    
    if (i > 0) {
      pasteRow = +pasteRow + +copyRows
    }
    
    // build the range to paste into - it starts on pasteRow and paste col, 
    // and is as many rows as the copied range, and as many columns as the copied range
    let pasteRange = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteRow, pasteCol, copyRows, copyCols);
    
    // put the values from copyValues into the pasteRange
    pasteRange.setValues(copyValues);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial on loops - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: Fantastic Kris... I've now a great handle on the re-iteration ( for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)) and the relocation of that iteration paste.
Much, much thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help.  I remember how hard it was starting out.   If you like the answer, could you click the accept answer checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

```
function xmacro() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Full')
      const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Dump')
      ssh.getRange('BK3:BT34').copyTo(dsh.getRange('A1'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```